# Can ARP with IP aliases on Windows be made to behave like on Unix?

Tags: windows, alias, arp

On FreeBSD, when I have one interface with two IPs:

```
ifconfig nic0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig nic0 alias 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255
```

If I ping the alias, if the host I'm pinging from, e.g. 192.168.0.20, is not yet in the ARP cache, this results in the the following ARP request:

```
Who has 192.168.0.20? Tell 192.168.0.1
```

In other words, the ARP request originates from the interface main IP.

On Windows 7 or Server 2008R2, however, if I configure my interface similarly:

```
netsh int ipv4 set address "LAN" static 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
netsh int ipv4 add address "LAN" 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.255 skipassource=true
```

When I do the same, it results in this ARP request:

```
Who has 192.168.0.20? Tell 192.168.0.2
```

Can this be changed so, that on Windows as well, ARP requests always originate from the main interface IP?